# OSError: libmkl_intel_lp64.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory, kaggle, huggingface-transformers, tpu

I am trying to run a model on TPU as given in [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/patil-suraj/exploring-T5/blob/master/T5_on_TPU.ipynb). The model was working fine, but today I could not run the model.

I used the following code to install pytorch-xla.

```
VERSION = "nightly"  #@param ["1.5" , "20200325", "nightly"]
!curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pytorch/xla/master/contrib/scripts/env-setup.py -o pytorch-xla-env-setup.py
!python pytorch-xla-env-setup.py --version $VERSION
```

I try to install required libraries as below:

```
!pip install -U nlp
!pip install sentencepiece
!pip install numpy --upgrade
```

However, when I try the following

```
import nlp
```

It gives the following error:

```
OSError: libmkl_intel_lp64.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I searched the error and I tried the followings, but still does not work. Any ideas how to fix it? Note: It was working a few days ago, however, today it is not.

```
!pip install mkl
#!export PATH="$PATH:/opt/intel/bin"
#!export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$PATH:opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/"
!export LID_LIBRAEY_PATH="$LID_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/"
```

Comment: Hi have you found the answer? I encountered the same problem in Colab

Comment: @Gabriel unfortunately I haven't found it yet

Comment: I am using this instead...

!pip install cloud-tpu-client==0.10 https://storage.googleapis.com/tpu-pytorch/wheels/torch_xla-1.8.1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl

but this would not be a nighty release

Comment: Thank you @Gabriel, I tried this, but I need to install the nightly version, as the trainer breaks on other versions in my case.

Comment: Same... I stuck at the training loop in second step within a epoch. However the  warning is from: from transformers import AdamW etc...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import os 
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']='/usr/local/lib'

!echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
!sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.so /usr/local/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.so.1
!sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libmkl_intel_thread.so /usr/local/lib/libmkl_intel_thread.so.1
!sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libmkl_core.so /usr/local/lib/libmkl_core.so.1

!ldconfig
!ldd /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so
```

worked for me. We will also try to fix the problem internally.